# Connection of a concrete Hamiltonian to the generator of time-translations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hamiltonian, time-evolution, unitarity

In a Quantum-mechanics lecture I am hearing we defined the Hamiltonian of a quantum system (a system with an observer) as the generator of the time translation-operation of the system under consideration.
$$
\exists H_S\in H(\mathcal{A}): exp(\frac{t}{i\hbar}H_S)
$$
describes the time evolution of the system from time $0$ to $t$ and $H(\mathcal{A})$ being the hermitian elements of the c*-algebra of this system.

**My Question**:
For a concrete system is there a way to derive from the above definition of the Hamiltonian the Hamiltonian that is commonly used for that concrete system?
E.g. for a 1-dimensional particle in a potential (that only depends on position) can I  derive the Hamiltonian which is often used: $a\hat{x}^2 + b\hat{p}^2$?

Comment: What does the statement "the Hamiltonian is $ax^2 + bp^2$" mean if not that that is the generator of time translations?

Comment: From Schrödinger's equation $i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle=H_S|\psi\rangle$
it follows that $H_S$ is the generator of time-translations.

Comment: Since when is "quantum system" a "system with an observer"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, mathematically, yes. If you know $\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle$ for every state $|\psi\rangle$ then you can calculate $\langle \phi|\frac{d}{dt}|\psi\rangle$ for every pair of states $\phi$ and $\psi$. This is equivalent to knowing all the matrix elements $i\langle \phi|H|\psi\rangle$ which suffices to know the operator $H$.

Whether this is practical even mathematically is another question.

If all you know is time-evolution $|\psi\rangle(t)$ for a specific state then figuring out the Hamiltonian is less straightforward. This is called an "inverse problem for the Schrodinger equation". Solutions can be found, though they have to make assumptions about boundary conditions and also the form of the Hamiltonian.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it helped. Have you ever seen this being done for the "simple" example I mentioned in the question? Could you perhaps give me a resource?

Comment: I have never seen it done as there's never really a physics situation where we know everything about all the states but don't already know the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 2):

Of course not - it is one property of the Hamiltonian, but it does not determine it. It leaves many options possible, like Hamiltonian of free particle, Hamiltonian of harmonic oscillator, Hamiltonian of particle in potential well, etc.